# Extracting Data from a STEP file to add to a database

Tags: database, solidworks, step, solidworksapi

Can anyone help suggest the best way to extract properties from a step file without having to open the file in SOLIDWORKS or another third party viewer. I'm trying to add part design data to a database, such as overall dimensions / volume / mass / and any custom properties that define the cad design. In the case of the assembly I'm trying to extract the indented BOM structure and the data for each of the sub assembly parts too.

I know properties can be exported from solid works or the data read through the SOLIDWORKS API, but I'm trying to avoid having to run solid works to get the part design data into the database.

Comment: Search for `.NET CAD component` on Google, there are many programmer tools that allow STEP or SolidWorks file reading and data extraction.